# Whats the non-jsx equivalent of dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: syntax, reactjs

I'm working through [the reactjs tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) but am trying to avoid jsx and use the virtual DOM manually. How do I do the equivalent of

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
```

Answer (score 17):

Found the answer plugging around the source code:

```
React.DOM.div({ dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
    __html: markdown.makeHtml(this.props.children.toString())
} });
```

or in coffeescript:

```
 R.div dangerouslySetInnerHTML: __html: markdown.makeHtml @props.children.toString()
```

Comment: @vipin8169 it is an example of something that might want to do this (eg a markdown renderer). Standard javascript rules - the right-hand of the `:` can be any value that you're trying to set to.

Comment: So effectively it is not required, we can just do `R.div dangerouslySetInnerHTML: __html: @props.children.toString()` to make this work.